# Unclassifiable statement

Tags: fortran, fortran90

please help me with this error, Im doing a chi-square program to determinate a correlation between 11 variables and it gaves me the following error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

```
subroutine chicuadrado(matriz,val1,n,o)
    implicit none
    integer::i,j,k,m
    real*8::suma1,suma2,total,porcentaje1,porcentaje2
    integer,intent(in)::n,o
    real*8,allocatable,intent(inout)::matriz(:,:),val1(:,:)
    real*8,allocatable::x(:),y(:),chi(:)
    allocate(x(n))
    allocate(y(n))
    allocate(chi(o))
    total=0
    suma1=0
    suma2=0
    porcentaje1=0
    porcentaje2=0
    !bucle para ralizar la suma de todos los elementos de
    do j=1,o,1
        chi(j)=0
        do i=1,n,1
            suma1=suma1+matriz(i,j)
            suma2=suma2+val1(i,1)
        end do
        total=suma1+suma2
        porcentaje1=suma1/total
        porcentaje2=suma2/total
        do k=1,n,1
            x(k)=porcentaje1*matriz(k,j)
            y(k)=porcentaje2*val1(k,1)
        end do
        do m=1,n,1
 (1)    chi(j)=chi(j)+(matriz(m,j)-x(m))**2)/x(m)+((val1(m,1)-y(m))**2)/y(m)
        end do
    end do
    write(*,*) chi
    deallocate(x)
    deallocate(y)
    deallocate(chi)
end subroutine
```

Answer (score 3):

```
chi(j)=chi(j)+(matriz(m,j)-x(m))**2)/x(m)+((val1(m,1)-y(m))**2)/y(m)
   1 0    1 0 1      2   1  2 10   X
```

Check your parentheses.